# Why does char 0x0 becomes 0xFF (255) in QT C++ QByteArray?

Tags: c++, qt

Via the USB, I send the following to my QT C++ application. As you can see, we are sending total 5 bytes of data to my QT C++ application.

```
/* Create array of prescalers */
uint8_t send_data_array[5] = {0};
uint8_t index = 0;

/* Fill the array */
send_data_array[index++] = SEND_BACK_PWM_PRESCALERS_MESSAGE_TYPE;
send_data_array[index++] = STM32_PLC_PWM0_To_PWM3_Get_Prescaler() >> 8;
send_data_array[index++] = STM32_PLC_PWM0_To_PWM3_Get_Prescaler();
send_data_array[index++] = STM32_PLC_PWM4_To_PWM7_Get_Prescaler() >> 8;
send_data_array[index++] = STM32_PLC_PWM4_To_PWM7_Get_Prescaler();

/* Send the data via USB */
CDC_Transmit_FS(send_data_array, index);
```

When I send data, it looks like this:

[image]

So when I recieve the data in my QT C++ application, it looks like this:

```
uint32_t MessageServiceThread::readPWMPrescalersFromSTM32PLC(QByteArray usbDataRaw, uint32_t byteIndex){
    pwmPrescaler[0] = (usbDataRaw.at(byteIndex) << 8) | usbDataRaw.at(byteIndex + 1);
    byteIndex += 2;
    pwmPrescaler[1] = (usbDataRaw.at(byteIndex) << 8) | usbDataRaw.at(byteIndex + 1);
    byteIndex += 2;
    uint16_t p0 =  pwmPrescaler[0];
    uint16_t p1 =  pwmPrescaler[1];
```

Where `usbDataRaw` contains the data. The first index of `usbDataRaw` contains the `message type` that describe what type of message it is. So the code above begins from index `1`, not index `0`.

Let's focusing on

```
 pwmPrescaler[0] = (usbDataRaw.at(byteIndex) << 8) | usbDataRaw.at(byteIndex + 1);
```

Here `pwmPrescaler` is declared as `uint16_t pwmPrescaler[2];` and
`usbDataRaw.at(byteIndex) = 0` and `usbDataRaw.at(byteIndex + 1) = 250`.

But when I combinde them as you can see, I get the number `65530`!

[image]

That's funny, because `-6/250` is `0xFA` or `250`. That means that a `0` must have to become `0xFF` right? Why else does `250` become `65530`?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is unspecified whether `char` is `signed` or `unsigned`.

`usbDataRaw.at(byteIndex + 1)` results in a `char` that intends stores the value `250`. It looks like on your platform `char` is `signed`, so this value is actually `-6`.

Arithmetic operations on integer types smaller than `int` get promoted to `int` before the operation is performed. From cppreference on [Integer promotion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_promotion) :

> prvalues of small integral types (such as `char`) may be converted to prvalues of larger integral types (such as `int`). In particular, arithmetic operators do not accept types smaller than `int` as arguments, and integral promotions are automatically applied after lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, if applicable. This conversion always preserves the value.

Note the last sentence : *"This conversion always preserves the value"*. The value being preserved in this case is `-6` not `250`. The `char` is promoted to an `int` with the value `-6` with a resulting of (assuming 32 bit `int`) `0xFFFFFFFA`. The same thing occurs for the left operand, but the preserved value is `0`, which is unchanged by the bitshift. Bitwise OR is then performed resulting in `0xFFFFFFFA`, and then truncated to `uint16_t` for `0xFFFA` or `65530`.

One solution is to cast the `char` to `unsigned char` first to allow the promotion to preserve the intended value, `250` in this case.

Live example : https://godbolt.org/z/PP8rKqab7

Comment: So i have to cast the char to uint8_t? Just like that? I thought that will be done by it self if I just give the char value to an uint8_t variable.

Comment: `usbDataRaw` is a `QByteArray` which returns `char`. At some point that `uint8_t` was cast to a `char`, regardless of how you provided it initially.